# Copying elements from array by file

Tags: arrays, sorting, file-handling, bubble-sort

I am fetching the data from file line by line and storing them in word array

- i want to copy the whole word into another array like if wrd has assssh in current iteration i want it whole to be copied to arr array
- but what is been doing the first element in each iteration is copied in arr[i] but that is not what i want

i want the whole word to be copied at each index, actually after that i am sorting the word according to first alphabet in each array please help out

```
    while (fscanf(file, " %1023s", wrd) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n", wrd);
    //Pushing the result into vector
    //strcpy(arr,wrd);
    arr[i]=wrd[0];
    i++;
    counter++;

  }
 bubbleSortAWriteToB(arr, s_arr);
```

Comment: That is one long and hard to understand sentence. Maybe try to divide it up into several and perhaps add an example of in data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Assumeing 'arr' is a two dimentional array and 'wrd' is a character array, your code should look something like below in order to achieve what you want:

```
while (fscanf(file, " %1023s", wrd) == 1) {
    printf("%s\n", wrd);
    // calculating length of the wrd array
    int wrd_length = (int)( sizeof(wrd) / sizeof(wrd[0]); 
    int idx = 0;
    while(idx < wrd_length) {
       arr[i][idx] = wrd[idx];
       idx++;        
    }
    i++;
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: The array should be 1 dimensional and the sizeof(wrd) is always one